# Implicit declaration is invalid warning for __set_BASEPRI() function in Keil

Tags: stm32, interrupts, keil, gpio-external-interrupt

I'm trying to use a `__set_BASEPRI()` function in Keil to set up interrupts in STM32F407 but it doesn't work when I compile the code and  the IDE shows warning "implicit declaration of function '__set_BASEPRI' is invalid in C99". Functions `__enable_irq()`  and `__disable_irq()`  work fine. How do I make it work?

Also weird, when I click on "Go to definition" on all these functions, the IDE cannot find the source file for them even though cmsis_armcc.h is included in the project.

Comment: Do a text file search for "__set_BASEPRI" in all the .h file you have at disposal. Probably you will gather some info.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica its included in cmsis_armcc.h, cmsis_armclang.h and cmsis_gcc.h. The former is included in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in a compiler I was using. By default Keil uses ARMCC (default compiler 5). When I switched to ARMCLANG (default compiler 6), the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

`__get_BASEPRI()` is defined in cmsis_armcc.h, but only if `__TARGET_ARCH_7E_M` (ARMv7-M, Cortex-M3) or `__TARGET_ARCH_7E_M` (ARMv7E-M, Cortex-M4, M7) is defined.  The BASEPRI special register is not supported in ARMv6-M, Cortex-M0, M0+, and M1.  Make sure you have the correct device selected in the Options for Target dialog.

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when the prototype is not included. Have you included the relevant .h file?

Comment: Keil includes cmsis_armcc.h automatically. Including it manually doesn't fix the problem. I also tried a fresh Keil install on another PC and everything works fine, so this is probably an IDE problem, not my code. Reinstalling Keil on my PC didn't help.

Comment: @Archimedes If a re-install did not fix it on your machine but did on another, that suggests something is "left behind" in the registry